# SQL Server 2012 to Excel 2010 Copy and Paste

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2012, copy-paste

I am trying to copy and paste from SQL Server 2012 to Excel 2010.

My query has the 13th column that is delimiting  that is ruining the results.

It has a long description field that gets cut off after a space or a certain amount of characters.

It doesn't matter how big or small my order might be or how dumb my questions are, I get great service quickly. My account manager constantly comes through for me, and is the reason all of my purchasing inquiries start with blah

Please help.

1. I have tried the following methods
2. Tried saving without any delimiting to the Excel FIle
3. Changing the Query Results to add Quote Strings contianing list separators when saving .csv or copying result.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have already used TextToColumn in this instance of Excel. Close Excel. Restart Excel. Execute the query in (I assume you mean) Sql Server Management Studio (AKA SSMS). Left-Click the square in the top left of the results to select all the rows in the query results windows. Then Right-click and select Copy With Headers. Then go back to Excel, select cell A1 and paste. The headers should take care of the column splitting.

Hth,
Ojf

Comment: Doesn't work. I removed all delimiting settings, and still had the same problem.

Comment: I imported the document from SQL to Google Docs and faced the problem, therefore I'm concluding its a problem on the SQL end.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are able to Export data using DTS Import Export Wizard of SQL SERVER 2012.

Try saving in both Excel(.xls) and Comma Separted file(.csv).